# How to speed up sql left join?

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

I have the following table

```
lon, lat, heat
45,43,10,
...,...,...,
```

I would like to assign a unique id to all the unique couples of (lon, lat) variables. Currently I am doing the following using SqliteStudio:

```
/* Stack the two SQL tables one on top of the other*/
CREATE table NewTable (lon REAL, lat REAL, heat REAL);

INSERT INTO NewTable 
SELECT lon, lat, heat FROM heat_1
UNION 
SELECT lon, lat, heat FROM heat_2;

/* Associate unique id to lon, lat couples */

CREATE TABLE id_table (id_ integer primary key autoincrement, lon real, lat real);
INSERT INTO id_table(lon, lat) SELECT lon, lat FROM DataFrameStack GROUP BY lon, lat;
  
/*CREATE TABLE output*/

CREATE TABLE output_table AS
SELECT
   NewTable.lon, NewTable.lat, heat, id_
FROM
   NewTable
LEFT JOIN id_table ON
   ((NewTable.lon = id_table.lon) AND
   (NewTable.lon = id_table.lon));
```

The issue however is that I have a large number of rows (in the order of millions) and it is painfully slow. What is the most efficient way of achieving the result?

Comment: The "ON" clause compares two times the same value pairs, that looks like a bug.  More important, did you introduce proper indexes on lon and lat in id_table?

Comment: Are you aware that `UNION` spends resources removing any duplicates?  But that `UNION ALL` doesn't *(making it much quicker)*?

Comment: @MatBailie Hi, no I am not. I will improve that! I use sql maybe once or twice per year so I barely know how to get by..

Answer (score 0):

If you have sqlite release after SQLite Release 3.25.0, then you can do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE output_table AS
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lon, lat ORDER BY lon ASC) ROWNUM, lon, lat, heat
FROM
(SELECT lon, lat, heat FROM heat_1
UNION 
SELECT lon, lat, heat FROM heat_2) Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY lon, lat) as id,
       ll.*
FROM (SELECT lon, lat, heat FROM heat_1
      UNION 
      SELECT lon, lat, heat FROM heat_2
     ) ll;
```

I'm not sure why you are involving intermediate tables.  Also, `UNION` slows down the query, because it incurs overhead to remove duplicates.  If you don't need to remove duplicates, use `UNION ALL`.